# Getting a ResultSet from ExecuteQuery() not properly executing

Tags: javascript, sql, jsp, object

The follow block of code is some that I have tried working out. I have set test checks throughout my JSP page and it is not getting past the 3.22, thus ending the program. THere is another set of relations that need to be committed below but I assuming it is not going through.

I am using PostgreSQL. All of the data being pulled is from an HTML form (basically a registration form).

I got the first INSERT to work for the Users table, and it is working quite well. Following the same syntax, I figure I could pull the userid that is created (it is automatically created from a sequence relation in my database schema). However, this is not working as to plan when I am trying to find the userid from that same USers table (from the newly created tuple I made) so I can use it to create a new Locations row. I tried looking everywhere, and I am out of ideas. Would I need to put this block in a different JSP page? A different connection? CLose and reopen the connection? Any ideas would be great.

Thanks!

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.lang.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.naming.*"%>

<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<jsp:useBean id="DbConnection"
             class="edu.bu.cs.cs460.photoshare.DbConnection">
    <jsp:setProperty name="DbConnection" property="*"/>
</jsp:useBean>

<%
out.println("test check 1");

String email = request.getParameter("email");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
String lname = request.getParameter("lname");

int dob = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("dob"));

out.println("test check 2: " + email + " " + password + " " + fname + " " + lname + " " + dob);

try{
    PreparedStatement st_users = null;
    Connection myCon = null;
    out.println("test check 2.21");
    try {
       Context ctx = new InitialContext();
       if (ctx == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("No Context");
       }
       DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/postgres");
       if (ds == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Datasource not found");
       }
       myCon = ds.getConnection();
       if (myCon == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not get connection");
       }


      } catch (SQLException e) {
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
      } catch (NamingException e) {
       throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }



    PreparedStatement getUID = null;    

    getUID=myCon.prepareStatement("SELECT MIN(\"user_id\") FROM \"Users\" as U WHERE \"U.email\" = ?");
    getUID.setString(1, email);
    out.println("test check 3.22");
    ResultSet rs = null;
    rs = getUID.executeQuery();

    out.println("test check 3.999");
    int userid = rs.getInt(1);

    getUID.close();

    //String tempuserid = (String)rs.getAttribute(1);
    //int userid = rs.getInt(1);
    //sint userid = Integer.parseInt(tempuserid);

    out.println("test check 4: " + userid);
    /* now we have the ID from the set  */

    /* this will set the location tabe now for the registered user */

    PreparedStatement st_loc = null;

    st_loc=myCon.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO \"Locations\" (\"user_id\", \"curLoc\", \"hcity\", \"hstate\", \"country\") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

    String hcity = request.getParameter("city");
    String hstate = request.getParameter("state");
    String curLoc = " ";
    String country = request.getParameter("country");

    out.println("test check 5: " + hcity + " " + hstate + " " + curLoc + " " + country);

    st_loc.setInt(1, userid);
    st_loc.setString(2, curLoc);
    st_loc.setString(3, hcity);
    st_loc.setString(4, hstate);
    st_loc.setString(5, country);   

    st_loc.executeUpdate();

    out.println("test check 6:");
    st_loc.close();
    myCon.close();
    out.println("Data is successfully inserted into database.");
}
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);

}

%>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue I see is that you are unnecessarily quoting your table and column names in your queries.  For instance:

```
"SELECT MIN(\"user_id\") FROM \"Users\" as U WHERE \"U.email\" = ?"
```

...will work much better as:

```
"SELECT MIN(user_id) FROM Users as U WHERE U.email = ?"
```

Note that this applies to your `INSERT` statement as well.  And why are you using `MIN(user_id)`?  Do you allow a single e-mail address to have multiple user accounts?  Because that's probably not the approach you want.

Also, it's not clear what you mean when you say "I got the first INSERT to work".  There's only one INSERT statement in your code, and it comes after the SELECT statement.  Do you mean that somewhere else you have code that inserts a row into the `Users` table, and you are confident that it is correct?

Some general recommendations:

1. Don't put Java code inside of your JSP files.  In particular, business logic related to getting a connection to the database and constructing and executing queries has no place in a JSP.  JSP's are intended to provide your webapp's interface/view, not to house its core business logic.
2. Consider using an ORM framework like Hibernate.  You'll likely find that it's a lot more pleasant to work with than manually constructed JDBC queries.

Comment: I see what you are saying about the JSPs and not housing database queries. For the sake of this project though, I am just aiming for the functionality and not for the security and construction. If I did go about this though, would going through Java objects work? Also, I am much familiar doing SQL queries in PHP, so doing this in Java/SQL is different. Also, I don't know if it matters for the queries, but this is PostgreSQL and not mySQL.